# Apple Mac slow running program through parallels to window to revit

Tags: mac

Seem to lack ram to run revit program through installed windows 7 using parallels. It takes hours to complete task. Mac is 8 gig all in one. Wondering why so slow. Can it be better?

Comment: We need a lot more information than you provided to be able to help.  What is your definition of slow?  How long would the same task take if you ran it using Windows 7 on Boot Camp?  What is the revit program and how much memory does it need? How much memory have you assigned the virtual machine?  Does the program use a lot of disk I/O? Does it use a lot of graphics like Photoshop does? Have you tried using VMware fusion instead of parallels?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set windows number of cores to the highest possible and windows ram to 4GB?
This solved a lot of speed problems to me...